# UICollectionViewCells disappear when going out of UICollectionView frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Consider the following:

I have a UICollectionView with a size of 400x400. This UICollectionView has 5 UICollectionViewCells which also have a size of 400x400.

Clip to bounds is set to false so that my UICollectionViewCells will be visible (this does not work, I can only see 1). I want this so I can use paging. When I start scrolling there are 2 cells, but when the scrolling snaps, the previous cell disappears and I can only see 1 cell.

I use dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier to retrieve cells to fill the collectionview. Can this be part of the problem?

How can I display the UICollectViewCells that are out of the collection view's frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. What you describe for a problem is actually a feature of `UICollectionView` and `UITableView`. They reuse the cells that are not visible for performance and memory reasons. You might think of another approach like `UICollectionView` with custom layout if that would be possible for your requirement or directly use `UIScrollView` with paging and you rearrange all the views while is scrolling.

Comment: I used a different approach as explained in my question: Disabled paging on the UICollectionView, increased it's frame and implemented the paging myself with the scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating delegate method. thx